# Accessing a hash

Tags: perl

How do I further access this hash? Upon using below dumper,

```
print Dumper(\%LinkData);
```

The result is

```
$VAR1 = {
          'AlternativeTo::Source' => {
                                     'ITSMConfigItem' => [
                                                         {
                                                           'Type' => 'Link',
                                                           'Content' => 'CI:0523000006',
                                                           'Link' => '/otrs5/index.pl?Action=AgentITSMConfigItemZoom;ConfigItemID=24',
                                                           'Title' => 'ConfigItem# 0523000006 (Hardware): Hardware 2'
                                                         }
                                                       ]
                                   },
          'DependsOn::Source' => {
                                 'ITSMConfigItem' => [
                                                     {
                                                       'Type' => 'Link',
                                                       'Content' => 'CI:0523000005',
                                                       'Link' => '/otrs5/index.pl?Action=AgentITSMConfigItemZoom;ConfigItemID=22',
                                                       'Title' => 'ConfigItem# 0523000005 (Hardware): Hardware 1'
                                                     }
                                                   ]
                               },
          'Includes::Target' => {
                                'ITSMConfigItem' => [
                                                    {
                                                      'Type' => 'Link',
                                                      'Content' => 'CI:0523000006',
                                                      'Link' => '/otrs5/index.pl?Action=AgentITSMConfigItemZoom;ConfigItemID=24',
                                                      'Title' => 'ConfigItem# 0523000006 (Hardware): Hardware 2'
                                                    }
                                                  ]
                              }
        };
```

How can I tidy it up to something like

```
AlternativeTo :: ITSMConfigItem :: ConfigItem# 0523000006 (Hardware): Hardware 2

DependsOn :: ITSMConfigItem :: ConfigItem# 0523000005 (Hardware): Hardware 1

Includes :: ITSMConfigItem :: ConfigItem# 0523000006 (Hardware): Hardware 2
```

Currently, code below only managed :

```
    foreach my $link_name (sort keys %LinkData) 
    {
        foreach my $subject (keys %{ $LinkData{$link_name} }) 
        {
            my @ActualLinkName = split('::', $link_name);
            print "$ActualLinkName[0] :: $subject\n";

        }
    }

/*
AlternativeTo :: ITSMConfigItem
DependsOn :: ITSMConfigItem
Includes :: ITSMConfigItem
*/
```

Comment: Your code is already on the right track. What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: This smells like some parsed XML. If so, the answer is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is to access the lowest level of your data structure.

```
print "$ActualLinkName[0] :: $subject :: $LinkData{$link_name}->{$subject}->[0]->{Title}\n";
```

Let's take a look at this. The call on its own is the following. I'll break it down for you.

```
#                                       4444444
#                                  333
#                      2222222222              
#        111111111111
$LinkData{$link_name}->{$subject}->[0]->{Title}
```

Here's your data structure, re-indented. The numbers above refer to the depths inside the structure.

```
(                                                    
   'AlternativeTo::Source' => {                 # 1
     'ITSMConfigItem' => [                      # 2
       {                                        # 3
         'Type'    => 'Link',
         'Content' => 'CI:0523000006',
         'Link'    => '/otrs5/index.pl?Action=AgentITSMConfigItemZoom;ConfigItemID=24',
         'Title'   => 'ConfigItem# ...'         # 4
       }
     ]
   },
   # ...
```

1. The outside structure is a hash, so we don't need a `->` dereferencing operator. We just access a key in the hash. Note the round parentheses `()` as opposed to curly braces `{}` on references.
2. Behind that key `$link_name` is a hash reference. We use the `->` to access its key `$subject`.
3. Behind that key there is an array reference. Because there is always just one entry, we can simply use index `0` as a fixed value.
4. And inside there there's another hash reference, but the keys are always fixed, so we can just access the one called `'Title'`.

Note that you can also omit all the arrows `->` if you prefer that syntax because Perl is smart enough to know those have to be references.

```
$LinkData{$link_name}{$subject}[0]{Title}
```

This means the same thing. I personally like the arrows as I find them easier to read.

---

You might want to read [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html), [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Comment: yeah..you are right..i want to go deeper..thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output listed as:

```
AlternativeTo :: ITSMConfigItem :: ConfigItem# 0523000006 (Hardware): Hardware 2
DependsOn :: ITSMConfigItem :: ConfigItem# 0523000005 (Hardware): Hardware 1
Includes :: ITSMConfigItem :: ConfigItem# 0523000006 (Hardware): Hardware 2
```

You can structure your loop like this, assuming all your data is like the dump provided:

```
foreach my $key (keys %$hash){
     # split and get the first element of the array
     my $name = (split('::', $key))[0];

     # Get the ITSMConfigItem from the hashmap and grab the first array 
     # element contained therein, assuming there is only 1 element in the array
     my $item = ${$hash->{$key}->{ITSMConfigItem}}[0]; 

     # One line output
     print "$name :: ITSMConfigItem :: $item->{Title}\n"
}
```

Comment: Down voting is okay, but please leave a comment as to why you down vote any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data structure is exactly as shown:

```
foreach my $link_name (sort keys %LinkData) {
    print '' . (split('::', $link_name))[0] . " :: ITSMConfigItem :: " . ${$LinkData{$link_name}{'ITSMConfigItem'}}[0]->{'Title'} . "\n";
}
```

A more generic approach would be:

```
foreach my $key1 (sort keys %LinkData) {
    foreach my $key2 (sort keys %{$LinkData{$key1}}) {
        foreach my $innerHash(@{$LinkData{$key1}{$key2}}) {
            print '' . (split('::', $key1))[0] . " :: $key2 :: " .$innerHash->{'Title'} . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```